# Accessing dictionary items added by another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Here is my code -

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<int,BitmapSource> Cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<int,BitmapSource>(5, 199);

    int width = 720;
    int height = 480;
    int stride = (width * 3 / 4 ) * 4 + 4;
    int currentframe = 0;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                for (int i = -9; i < 9; i++)
                {
                    if (!Cache.ContainsKey(currentframe + i))
                    {
                        RenderFrameToCache(currentframe + i);
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        });
        t.Start();
    }
    private object locker = new object();
    private void RenderFrameToCache(int frame)
    {
            byte[] pixels;
            //Create byte array
            BitmapSource img = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr24, null, pixels, stride);
            Cache.AddOrUpdate(frame, img, (x,y) => img);
    }

    private BitmapSource GetBmpSource(int frame)
    {
        if (Cache.ContainsKey(frame))
        {
            return Cache[frame];
        }
        else
        {
            RenderFrameToCache(frame);
            return Cache[frame];
        }
    }

    private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        Cache.Clear();
        image.Source = new BitmapImage();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        currentframe++;
        image.Source = GetBmpSource(currentframe);

    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        currentframe--;
        image.Source = GetBmpSource(currentframe);

    }
}
```

The second thread is supposed to fill the dictionary with items so that they are on hand when the Window wants to display them.
Whenever a button is pressed, there is an InvalidOperationException.  What is the problem?

Comment: Show the code you use to try to read the values in the dictionary.

Comment: You're having a data race. You can't add elements to a dictionary *while* you're reading them on another thread. It's fine to read from many threads at once, but writing requires exclusive access.

Comment: In additem(), I have a lock statement around the code that is adding the item, and it doesn't work.  Is that what I'm supposed to do?

Comment: Please make a [short self contained complete example](http://sscce.org/), where does `key` in `dict.ContainsKey(key)` come from? There are too many things missing in your code for us to figure out where your problem is. Also you said you tried with concurrent dictionary, did it work? Did you get the same error, did you get a new error? what line is the error happening on?

Comment: I have edited the question.  Hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: Have you tried passing the cache in at the start of the thread and then, instead of sleeping in the thread, start the thread every 250 ms?

Comment: I just tried it, and it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.
I had to use BitmapSource.Freeze each time I added a new BitmapSource.
This link is what explained it - [Multi threading in WPF using C# (with background worker)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861448/multi-threading-in-wpf-using-c-sharp-with-background-worker?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Use thread safe `ConcurrentDictionary`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> All these operations [TryAdd, TryUpdate, ...] are atomic and are thread-safe with regards to
>   all other operations on the ConcurrentDictionary class.
>   [...] For modifications and write operations to the dictionary,
>   ConcurrentDictionary uses fine-grained locking to ensure
>   thread safety. (Read operations on the dictionary are performed in a
>   lock-free manner.)

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work.  If I am being unclear about anything please tell me.

Comment: @phil Can you post the code where you used ConcurrentDictionary and didn't work?

Comment: @phil I bet we are missing some code. Please either post the whole code or create a simple test case that produces the error. I did a quick and dirty test and couldn't generate the error you have.