# 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, opencv, .net-4.5

I'm not sure what to do! I'm trying to run OpenCV in a background thread and have it send the image to the dispatcher. Here's a (distilled) version of the code:

```
private Thread _thread
private void WindowLoaded(){
   _thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(OpenCV)); //Run in seperate thread
   _thread.Start();
}
private void OpenCV(){
   //CV Image Capturing and parsing etc - works fine!
   //...

   //Problems begin
   System.Drawing.Bitmap bm = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(gray); //Get a usable image from CV
   bm.SetResolution(640.0f, 480.0f); //Change its resolution
   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { //Invoke this to be run in main thread
       updateImage(bm); //Code that updates UI
   }));
}
private void updateImage(System.Drawing.Bitmap img) {
    ImageSourceConverter c = new ImageSourceConverter(); 
    //Console.WriteLine(c == null); //No success in testing for nulls!
    MyImage.Source = (ImageSource)c.ConvertFrom(img); //The problem is here
}
```

In the last line of `updateImage` The error in the title happens. I have seen many other people exqperiencing very similar problems, but none of their solutions seem to work.

MyImage is not null when the exception is called, nor is c or img. However, MyImage.Source is.

Comment: Check also MyImage for null.

Comment: Which of the variables *is* null? Did you debug?

Comment: I have checked MyImage and it is not null. Neither is, as far as I can see, c or img. However, when the error occurs, MyImage.Source is null, which means that the ConvertFrom or casting is creating a null. I will add this to the question

Comment: How do I protest the duplicate status? I don't believe it is!

Comment: Did you try c.CanConvertFrom(img.GetType())?

Comment: @drnessie: It is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861448/multi-threading-in-wpf-using-c-sharp-with-background-worker (the answer is there too btw).

Comment: @sondergard It's returning false! Looks like this has just changed question type!

Comment: @drnessie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94456/load-a-wpf-bitmapimage-from-a-system-drawing-bitmap

Comment: @sondergard THANK YOU! PS: Can the duplicate status be changed to match what it is really a duplicate of?

Comment: No sorry, don't know how to change the duplication link